# how to split blender into two windows so that one has "edit mode" and the other has "object mode"

Tags: edit-mode

I found the same topic on the forum,
but I didn't find the answer to my question,
so I'll ask again
I threw off the screenshot, edited in Photoshop, so that it would be clearer what I want::[image]

Comment: I don't know if you refer to this forum or not, but it is basically impossible at this moment : https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Tjfbbc/?sorting=hot

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you can see the two windows at the same time (like from a second monitor), it is impossible (for now, and it may stay like this). The mode of an Object is like a state it is in and the object just can't be in two different states at the same time.
You probably have noticed that when you switch from one Mode to another, you can undo it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> which means that switching from Modes actually **changes the state of an object** and a soon as you do that you see the little star near the name of your Blend file indicating that you **have made changes to the Blend file** :

[image]

so you are basically asking for a feature that allows you to view your Blend file in two different versions simultaniously. That's basically time travel and only softwares like GIT can do that.

Also there are actions that you can perform only on one Mode like removing/applying modifiers or deleting a material slot for example.

I want you to understand here that I am talking about Blender and how it handles "Modes" at the code level (since it may be different in other softwares), the answers in the link that @MikoCG gave explains some of the reason why it is (and may always be) impossible.

But in my opinion, from a user experience point of view, you don't really need to have the object in two modes at the same time, it won't make sense, since, for example when you press <kbd>G</kbd> Edit mode, you don't change the object's position (the origin point) you only move the vertices but if you do that in Object mode, you move the origin point therefore changing the location of the object.

I do understand what you mean, tho, and this is the reason why they implemented Mode auto-switch when you move from workspace to another in `2.8+`.